# Flutter (dart) ListView Builder Widget giving Invalid Arguments Error

Tags: dart, flutter

So, I have created a basic map

```
     var tracks = const [
    {
      'title':'Something',
      'subtitle':'Something'
    },
    {
      'title':'Something Else',
    },
    {
      'title':'Admission',
    },
    {
      'title':'University',
    },
    {
      'title':'Exam',
'subtitle':'Something'
    },
    {
      'title':'Job',
    },
  ];
```

And this is being called by a `ListView.builder` in the following manner:

```
var trackTitles = tracks[index];
```

and then being used like this:

```
return PrimaryMail(
              title: trackTitles['titles'],
            )
```

But, it is throwing an `"Invalid Argument(s): titles` error in the final build. No dart-analytics issues seen. The only error I see (info, not serious) is  `This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final: Home.tracks (must_be_immutable] lib\main.dart:18)`. [edit: the immutable issue has been fixed now by replacing `var` with `final`, but the original problem remains]

So, any way to understand why it is throwing an invalid argument even though the title key does exist?

The full code of this page is [here](https://gist.github.com/Eshpelin/d0dd2ded637e54fe96acb33f63c271df).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `final` before the field you declare in line lib\main.dart:18

If you have `var` there, replace `var` by `final`

Comment: Thank you. This solves the additional issue. But not the issue with `Invalid Argument(s): titles`. This error has now changed to `Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 237 pos 15: 'data != null': is not true.`

Note that if I replace `title: trackTitles['titles'],` with `title: 'Random String',`, then it seems to work normally.

Comment: Try `title: trackTitles['titles']?.isNotEmpty ?? 'no tile'`

Comment: Thank you. Just did. Now all of the tiles display "no tile". Which means that it is empty :(

But do note that I have 6 sets/maps in `tracks`, and `6` tiles are being printed too (with the 'no tile' text).

Comment: `title: trackTitles['titles'],` should be `title: trackTitles['title'],` (`title` instead of `titles`)

Comment: I misinterpreted your code. I deleted my comment and posted a new one above.

Comment: Actually, sorry. This just got solved. Thank you very much!